# cleaner way to handle python exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

I'm cleaning up some code, and have run into a handful of situations where there are repetitive cleanup actions in a try/except :

```
try:
    ...
except KeyError , e :
    cleanup_a()
    cleanup_b()
    cleanup_c()
    handle_keyerror()
except ValuesError , e :
    cleanup_a()
    cleanup_b()
    cleanup_c()
    handle_valueerror()
```

i'd like to make these a bit more standardized for readability and maintenance.  the "cleanup" actions seem to be local to the block , so it's not going to be much cleaner to do the following (though it will standardize it a bit):

```
def _cleanup_unified():
    cleanup_a()
    cleanup_b()
    cleanup_c()
try:
    ...
except KeyError , e :
    _cleanup_unified()
    handle_keyerror()

except ValuesError , e :
    _cleanup_unified()
    handle_valueerror()
```

can anyone suggest alternate ways of approaching this ?

Comment: I notice that there are very good responses that are actually answering two different questions.  Perhaps some clarification could be added as to which you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differenciate the Error by catching all of them in the same except, and testing the type like this:

```
try:
    ...
except (KeyError, ValuesError) as e :
    cleanup_a()
    cleanup_b()
    cleanup_c()
    if type(e) is KeyError:
        handle_keyerror()
    else:
        handle_valueerror()
```

Comment: thats a good idea.  IIRC, it would be better to `if isinstance(e,types.KeyError):`

Answer (score 1):

If the cleanup can always run, you can use the `finally` clause, which runs whether an exception is thrown or not:

```
try:
  do_something()
except:
  handle_exception()
finally:
  do_cleanup()
```

If the cleanup should *only* be run in the event of an exception, something like this might work:

```
should_cleanup = True
try:
  do_something()
  should_cleanup = False
except:
  handle_exception()
finally:
  if should_cleanup():
    do_cleanup()
```

Comment: i thought about your second option (with the `should_cleanup` flag.  it looked less readable for the long term.

Answer (score 0):

If the `except` block is always the same, you can write:

```
try:
    ...
except (KeyError, ValueError) , e :
    cleanup_a()
    cleanup_b()
    cleanup_c()
    handle_keyerror()
```

Comment: the difference is the handle_keyerror and handle_valueerror. The except block is not the same.